# Regex for string optionally divided by one blankspace

Tags: regex

I'm new to angular/javascript and need a regex which should allow one string optionally two strings with a blank space. Maximum 10 characters in total.

Valid strings: 
"asdf"
"asdf asdf"

I've tried similar to: ^[[a-z]{1,10} ?[a-z]{2,9}]{1,10}?$  but can't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantifiers only modify the behavior of the atom (subpattern) they stand next to. Also, your regex is "ruined" since you put all the subpattern sequences into a character class.

You may use

```
/^(?!.{11})[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XK5OBu/1)

If the char can be any non-whitespace char, replace `[a-z]` with `\S`.

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.{11})` - return no match if any 11 characters are found from the start of a string (this negative lookahead will work the same as `(?=.{1,10}$)` - any 1 to 10 chars up to the string end)
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase letters (replace with what you really allow)
- `(?: [a-z]+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - - a space (may be replaced with `\s`)
  - `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase letters (replace with what you really allow)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks! Your pattern works good for me with the exception of that I'm able to enter multiple blank spaces after the string(s)

Comment: Actually the pattern works perfectly when i test it on https://regex101.com but the problem with blank spaces occurs in the form where I use it

Comment: You may add `ng-trim="false"`.

Comment: I tweaked your pattern just slightly and it does what I want now, thank you!  ("^(?!.{11})[a-z]+ ?([a-z]+)?$")

Comment: @MartinNilsson: The `"^(?!.{11})[a-z]+ ?([a-z]+)?$"` expression will match an optional trailing space (in general). If it is what you need, then great. You did not post your code, so I could not help you with that tweaking part.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have to check second criteria (Maximum 10 characters in total) in regexp. If one has a hammer, he don't have to use it everywhere. Instead it's simple and straight-forward to exam string's length via `length` property.

```
s = 'asdf asdf'
/^\w+( \w+)?$/.test(s) && s.length <= 10
```

Comment: I've considered that but I think I'd prefer to use a regex if possible since I'm reusing it as a constant in several places

Comment: @MartinNilsson You can also wrap it into a function and reuse it.

Comment: I got multiple similar patterns in use already in the same manner so I'd still prefer the regex solution if I can get away with it